# Nonce Code or Nonce Timeout

Tags: c#, java, soap, nonce

My Client has a Java webservice and I am trying to consumem it using  wcf .

It uses a usernametoken with nonce, createddate.. This is the  link I am using 
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication, 
Following code generates nonce. This simply appends to the string.

```
    string phrase = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase);

protected string GetSHA1String(string phrase)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
    }
```

Error: The Nonce which is a randomly generated value has expired. Is the code generating a nonce or checksum? 
Soap UI does not give me this error. It is successful.This is obvious becuase Interoperability is always an issue

[SOAP Error, The nonce, which is a randomly generated value, has expired. ocurred while running action:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381910/soap-error-the-nonce-which-is-a-randomly-generated-value-has-expired-ocurred)

Thank you